# Jtree : Action handler if text changes?

Tags: java, event-handling, jtree

I'd like to have an action handler, when I edit a jTree line.
For exemple, as I need to update some values in a database, I need my program to detect if a line is being edited, so I can do what I want with this new line.

Is there any action handler who does it? "valueChanged" one detects the selection, not changes.

Otherwise, It could be even perfect if the action hadler detects when I exit from "editing a line", clicking on ENTER.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom TreeCellEditor, which informs you when input changes.
DefaultTreeCellEditor also has ability to inform you when *exit from editing a line*

Comment: Hello Ben, thank you for your help!
What is a TreeCellEditor? Is it simple to use?

Comment: That's ok, a made it! 
It's two lines :D
Thank you!